# How to reject a call on a 3rd device on Twilio

Tags: android, ios, twilio

I'm using android sdk and have a case like this:

- client_A calls client_B and client_B accepted -> client_A and client_B connected.
- client_C calls client_A that is talking to client_B -> there is an incoming call for person A.

I want client_C to receive busy status as soon as I make a call. How to reject client_C in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reject the call from the application by immediately calling [`reject` on the `CallInvite`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-voice-android/docs/5.0.2/com/twilio/voice/CallInvite.html#reject-android.content.Context-) when there is an existing call.

Or, in your webhook you could [use the Calls resource to list calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#read-multiple-call-resources) where your client identity is either the `To` or the `From`. If there are any calls, then instead of returning the `<Dial>` to the `<Client>` you can return [`<Reject reason="busy">`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/reject) to reject the call.